# How to compute the limit $\lim\limits_{t \to -\infty} (-(\frac{1}{2}te^{2t}-\frac{1}{4}e^{2t}))$?

Tags: limits

Question:

> $\lim\limits_{t \to -\infty} (-(\frac{1}{2}te^{2t}-\frac{1}{4}e^{2t}))$

My work:

$\lim\limits_{t \to -\infty} (-(\frac{1}{2}te^{2t}-\frac{1}{4}e^{2t}))$

$= \lim\limits_{t \to -\infty} (-e^{2t}(\frac{1}{2}t-\frac{1}{4}))$

$= \lim\limits_{t \to -\infty} (\frac{-e^{2t}}{\frac{1}{(\frac{1}{2}t-\frac{1}{4})}})$

$=\frac{-(-\infty)}{0}$

$=\frac{\infty}{0}$

Comment: The limit is $0$

Answer (score 2):

Write it as $\frac {t}{2e^{-2t}} $ then apply L hospital and second  one is directly $0$ as $e^{-\infty }=0$

Answer (score 0):

Instead of going with limit $t \to -\infty$, substitute $t$ with $-t$ and calculate limit $t \to \infty$ which becomes

$$\lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{1}{4} \frac{2t+1}{e^{2t}}$$

You can see that denominator grows asymptotically faster than nominator, the limit is $0$. Or just use L'Hospital.